# Solve a Sudoku with A* search

Tags: performance, search, a-star, sudoku

I want to solve a Sudoku using A* search, because it's so fast. I wrote the code with backtracking and breadth first search. All the searches are too slow. When I gave a hard Sudoku puzzle, it took ~10 min to get solve. Too slow. A* search has a linear time complexity and it's awesome.
Just a tip to how to pick 'h' and 'g' 
what is the best heuristic for this?

Comment: Please include your code so far.

Comment: `"Just a tip to how to pick 'h' and 'g'` What?

Comment: thanks for reply . we know that in a* search we have a function(f) that lead us to the answer. f contain h and g . h is the heuristic and g is the cost . what is the best heuristic for solving Sudoku !!!!

Comment: A* is sort of linear (but not really) in the size of the search space, which is itself exponential in the size of your sudoku board. So that doesn't help. And there are no helpful costs as far as I can see, since it doesn't make any difference which cells you fill in and in what order, you have to fill them all anyway. Your best bet is probably to implement better constraint propagation.

Comment: i wanna use A* because its faster (and my professor said ....) . but don't know that how can i move on the graphs . how can i find a best heuristic to solve it.